# Using wildcard (*) or _all for index name in RemoveAction messes up AddAction in the same bulk alias update

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, alias

I am trying to point my alias to a new index. Before I associate my alias with the index, I want to remove all existing associations for that alias. This is what I am doing:

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "alias": "myAlias",
        "index": "*"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "alias": "myAlias",
        "index": "myIndex"
      }        
    }
  ]
}
```

This command, instead of adding 'myAlias' to just 'myIndex', it adds it to all existing indices.

I was expecting "myAlias" to be pointing to only "myIndex" instead of all indices. I also tried "_all" instead of wildcard, but that did not change the behavior.

Elasticsearch version is 7.10.2

result of "GET /_aliases" before I run my update

```
{
  "service-log-qa-2023.10.31-1" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "service-log-qa-2023.10.31-1-trace-write" : {
        "is_write_index" : true
      },
      "ai-service-copperfield-log-trace" : { }
    }
  },
  "ingestion-000052" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "ingestion-share" : {
        "is_write_index" : false
      }
    }
  },
  "myindex__1102_1" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "myalias_primary" : { }
    }
  },
  "myindex__1102_2" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "myalias_secondary" : { }
    }
  }
  "testerror-1781" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "alias-testerror" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the command I run

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "alias": "myalias_primary",
        "index": "*"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "alias": "myalias_primary",
        "index": "myindex_1102_2"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "alias": "myalias_secondary",
        "index": "*"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "alias": "myalias_secondary",
        "index": "myindex_1102_3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is what "GET /_aliases" return after the above update.

```
{
  "service-log-qa-2023.10.31-1" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "service-log-qa-2023.10.31-1-trace-write" : {
        "is_write_index" : true
      },
      "ai-service-copperfield-log-trace" : { },
      "myalias_primary" : { },
      "myalias_secondary" : { }
    }
  },
  "ingestion-000052" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "ingestion-share" : {
        "is_write_index" : false
      },
      "myalias_primary" : { },
      "myalias_secondary" : { }
    }
  },
  "myindex__1102_1" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "myalias_primary" : { },
      "myalias_secondary" : { }

    }
  },
  "myindex__1102_2" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "myalias_primary" : { },
      "myalias_secondary" : { }
    }
  },
  "myindex__1102_3" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "myalias_primary" : { },
      "myalias_secondary" : { }
    }
  }
  "testerror-1781" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "alias-testerror" : { },
      "myalias_primary" : { },
      "myalias_secondary" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that one of the indices that has myAlias is closed, read/only or you don't have access right to it? Can you post GET _aliases before and after the command?

Comment: I dont think that is the case. Because if I just use remove command, it removes the alias from all indices. I updated the question with the details you asked for.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are describing. Are these indices part of some data stream or there are some other details that you have omitted? I tried this - https://gist.github.com/imotov/dd349b5b84acf4c32386e69266f0054c It works fine.